# How to Delete all Cookies on my site except for one

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the following function to clear all cookies, which works.
This is clearing out the `PHPSESSID` too as far as I can tell. I want to retain just that one cookie alone.

I added the line: `if (name == "PHPSESSID") {...`
...to try and catch, and skip, altering the cookie names `PHPSESSID`, but it doesn't catch it for some reason.

Is there a clear reason why it's not catching, or is there a better way to achieve clearing all cookies except for "`PHPSESSID`"?

The Function:

```
function clearCookies() {

    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var equals = cookies[i].indexOf("=");
        var name = equals > -1 ? cookies[i].substr(0, equals) : cookies[i];
        if (name == "PHPSESSID") {
            alert("yes");
        }else{
            document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
            alert(name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you log the name and post what the output is?

Comment: And you're sure that cookie isn't httponly, if not you could just set it to httponly and it won't be accessible by javascript at all, which is a good thing

Comment: Try changing the session  name 'session_name('someName'); '  and then try

Comment: Well, when I put alert(name), it says "PHPSESSID" (w/o the quotes of course. So maybe on a more basic level, I don't understand why the "if(name == "PHPSESSID") part isn't catching. In chrome developer tools, it flat out says the name is "PHPSESSID".

Answer (score 1):

Hi I found the answer by using DevTool's console log instead of the cookie viewer. There's a space in front of PHPSESSID when it's set for some reason. So 
" PHPSESSID" works.

Solution here: output it in the console log instead of an alert.